# Test if Hardware Acceleration has been enabled for a CSS animation?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, hardware-acceleration

How can I tell *(for testing purposes)* if Hardware Acceleration has been enabled for a CSS animation?

I have the following code which essentially enlarges an element and makes it fullscreen (without using the HTML5 fullscreen API). It runs like a stuttering asthmatic tortoise on most mobiles when using a jQuery animation so I have used CSS3 instead.

Here is the jsFiddle example:

```js
$("#makeFullscreen").on("click", function() {        
   
    var map = $("#map"),
        mapTop = map.offset().top,
        mapLeft = map.offset().left;
    
    $("#map").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": mapTop,
        "left": mapLeft,
        "width": map.outerWidth(true),
        "height": map.outerHeight(true)
    });
    
    setTimeout(function(){map.addClass("fullscreen")},1);
    
    return false;        
});
```

```css
.mapContainer {    
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.map {  
    background: #00f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.fullscreen {
    -webkit-transition: top 300ms ease-out, height 300ms ease-out, left 300ms ease-out, width 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 300ms ease-out, height 300ms ease-out, left 300ms ease-out, width 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: top 300ms ease-out, height 300ms ease-out, left 300ms ease-out, width 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: top 300ms ease-out, height 300ms ease-out, left 300ms ease-out, width 300ms ease-out;
    transition: top 300ms ease-out, height 300ms ease-out, left 300ms ease-out, width 300ms ease-out;
    
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 100% !important;
}

#makeFullscreen {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mapContainer">
    <div id="map" class="map">
        <button id="makeFullscreen">Make Fullscreen</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This adds a class and the element transitions from one state to the next using a CSS transition. This is faster than jQuery but is still stuttery on iOS and android.

But I read [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) that you can force the transition to be accelerated using the GPU by specifying a 3d transform that essentially does nothing, like this:

```
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

However, after adding that to my CSS I see no visual improvement.

### The Question Then...

Is there a way to see if hardware acceleration has been enabled through dev tools in any browser? I don't need to detect this with script, I just want to know for testing purposes.

Comment: You can't tell directly.  The only thing I've seen people do is run some sort of performance test to test what performance is being produced.  As of several years ago, it was true that in some browsers, making your transition into a 3d transition can trigger more GPU support - I don't know what the current situation is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking hardware acceleration availability? (Testing available)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15310894), and [Check when css transforms are executed using hardware acceleration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25282715).

Comment: @TachyonVortex I don't want to use code to detect this and provide a fallback. I wondered if there is a way to do this through dev tools in any browser. I have altered my question to reflect this as I don't think this was clear originally.

Comment: I know this comment is not related with the question, but I have to share my experience using translate property. Please don't use it unless you really need, because after the element with this property the rendering engine is creating a new flow container and thus for example if you want to use fixed position  it will be rendered as relative position to the element with translate property. Read this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform/24808262#24808262

Comment: @Ivica Your comment is misleading. While `translate` might not be the best in the case of fixed positioning, it is *always* better for animations with other positioning. `fixed` positioning is by far the *exception*, not the standard.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

## Overview

A CSS property transition on an element is hardware-accelerated if all these conditions are met:

1. Hardware-accelerated layer compositing is enabled in the browser
2. The CSS property being transitioned is acceleratable
3. The element has been given its own compositing layer

Generally, the requirements for these conditions are:

1. The relevant hardware-acceleration options must be enabled, and the device's GPU and graphics drivers must not be blacklisted
2. Only compositing CSS properties (`opacity`, `transform: translate` / `scale` / `rotate`, etc) are acceleratable
3. Each browser has specific reasons for deciding whether to give an element its own compositing layer (or it can be forced by using a "go faster" hack like `transform: translate3d`)

---

## Hardware-accelerated layer compositing

To identify whether this is enabled:

### Chrome

#### 1. General acceleration

- Go to `chrome://settings`
- Click the **+ Show advanced settings** button
- In the **System** section, inspect the status of the **Use hardware acceleration when available** checkbox

If acceleration is enabled, then:

#### 2. Accelerated compositing

- Go to `chrome://gpu`
- In the **Graphics Feature Status** section, inspect the value of **Compositing**. This will be one of the following:

  - Hardware accelerated
  - Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable

More details on the Software Compositor from the [docs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome#TOC-Appendix-B:-The-Software-Compositor):

> In some situations hardware compositing is infeasible, e.g. if the device's graphics
>   drivers are [blacklisted](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/config/software_rendering_list_json.cc) or the device lacks a GPU entirely. For these situations is
>   an alternative implementation to the GL renderer called the SoftwareRenderer

(Note: Chrome also has a [Legacy Software Rendering Path](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome#TOC-Appendix-F:-The-Legacy-Software-Rendering-Path), which is "still lingering as of May 2014, but will soon be removed entirely in Blink.")

Here's a great article with more info: [Accelerated Rendering in Chrome](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/).

### Firefox

#### 1. General acceleration

- Go to Firefox's Preferences
- Go to the **Advanced** tab
- Go to the **General** subtab
- Inspect the status of the **Use hardware acceleration when available** checkbox

If acceleration is enabled, then:

#### 2. Layer acceleration

- Go to `about:config`
- Search for `layers.acceleration.disabled`

If layer acceleration is enabled (if the value is `false`), then:

#### 3. GPU accelerated windows

- Go to `about:support`
- In the **Graphics** section, inspect the value of **GPU Accelerated Windows**

If it does not begin with `0/`, and a rendering API is shown (eg. OpenGL, Direct3D), then GPU acceleration is active.

### Safari

- Enable Safari's debug menu by running this command in the Terminal:
  `defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1`
- Open (or restart) Safari
- In Safari's **Debug** menu, inspect the status of the **Disable Accelerated Compositing** option in the **Drawing/Compositing Flags** submenu

---

## Acceleratable CSS properties

The only CSS property transitions which can be hardware-accelerated are those which occur in the **compositing** stage of the rendering process. For example:

- [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)
- [`transform: translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate()) and its friends: [`translateX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translateX()), [`translateY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translateY()), [`translateZ`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translateZ()), [`translate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate3d())
- [`transform: scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scale()) and its friends: [`scaleX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scaleX()), [`scaleY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scaleY()), [`scaleZ`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scaleZ()), [`scale3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scale3d())
- [`transform: rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#rotate()) and its friends: [`rotateX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#rotateX()), [`rotateY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#rotateY()), [`rotateZ`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#rotateZ()), [`rotate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#rotate3d())

To fully benefit from acceleration, *no non-compositing properties must be transitioned*. For example:

- A transition on just `transform: translate` can receive the full benefit of acceleration (because the element's layer can simply be recomposited by the GPU).
- A transition on both `transform: translate` and `width` will receive *almost no benefit* from acceleration (because a transition on `width` causes the element's layer to be repainted by the CPU for every animation frame).

---

## Compositing layers & coloured borders

The browser's rendering engine decides (based on user preferences, CSS styles, etc) whether or not to give an element its own compositing layer.

For example, Chrome has [this list of reasons](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/#toc-layercreation), and also has this option in `chrome://flags`:

> **Compositing for RenderLayers with transitions**
>   Enabling this option will make RenderLayers with a transition on opacity, transform or filter have their own composited layer.

If an element has not been given its own layer, then no CSS transitions on that element will be accelerated.

`transform: translate3d` ([the "go faster" hack](http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/)) generally forces an element to be given its own layer.

But even if an element has been given its own layer, transitions on non-compositing properties (`width`, `height`, `left`, `top`, etc) *still cannot be accelerated*, because they occur before the compositing stage (eg. in the layout or paint stages). @ChrisSpittles This is why you saw no visual improvement after adding `transform: translate3d`.

Most browsers can display coloured borders around composited layers, to make them easy to identify for development/debugging:

### Chrome

Displaying the borders of composited layers can be done in one of two ways:

- *For all pages* — Go to `chrome://flags` and enable **Composited render layer borders** ("Renders a border around composited Render Layers to help debug and study layer compositing"). You'll need to relaunch Chrome for this to take effect.
- *For individual pages* — Open the Developer Tools, then open the Drawer, select the Rendering tab, and enable **Show composited layer borders**. Now, opening the Developer Tools on any page will cause layer borders to be shown on that page.

Now trigger the CSS transition on the element. If it has a coloured border, then it has its own compositing layer.

The border colours and their meanings are defined in [`debug_colors.cc`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/cc/debug/debug_colors.cc). More details [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings) and [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome#TOC-Appendix-E:-Debugging-composited-layers).

### Firefox

To draw the borders of composited layers:

- Go to `about:config`
- Search for `layers.draw-borders` and enable it

Now trigger the CSS transition on the element. If it has a coloured border, then it has its own compositing layer.

The border colours and their meanings are defined in [`Compositor::DrawDiagnosticsInternal`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/gfx/layers/Compositor.cpp).

### Safari

(This does not work for me with Safari 7.0.3, but it seems it did work for some people [as recently as last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17950283).)

Launch Safari from the Terminal with the `CA_COLOR_OPAQUE` boolean environment variable set:

```
$ CA_COLOR_OPAQUE=1 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

Alternative method:

```
$ export CA_COLOR_OPAQUE=1 
$ /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

Apparently, hardware-accelerated layers should be coloured red. More details [here](http://mir.aculo.us/2011/02/08/visualizing-webkits-hardware-acceleration/) and [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1998564&seqNum=4).

#### *Update:*

Here's an alternative method which works for me in Safari 7.0.3 (credit to [David Calhoun](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/mobile-performance-manifesto/#debugging-hardware-acceleration)):

- In Safari's **Debug** menu, enable **Show Compositing Borders** in the **Drawing/Compositing Flags** submenu

Now trigger the CSS transition on the element. If it has a coloured border, then it has its own compositing layer.

---

## References

For more details, check out these excellent articles:

- http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/optimization-and-performance/
- http://ariya.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/fluid-animation-with-accelerated.html

Comment: This was just what I was after. Thank you for the detailed information and outstanding answer.

Comment: Amazing answer, this is still helpful!

Comment: Is it the case that transform: scale(1.5) translate(10px 10px) would not get accelerated?