# How to improve the performance of this CSS animation?

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I am using **Chrome** and a pure `pulse` CSS animation

```
.pulse {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #53A653;
  border-radius: 100%;  
  -webkit-animation: scaleout 3.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: scaleout 3.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}



@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.0) }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JacksonTale/0ccbdwzp/1/).

I noticed that it is quite slow. Once I run it, the scrolling of the other windows of Chrome becomes not smooth and even now my typing is a little bit chunking.

Is CSS animation really this slow? or my CSS is just very bad? How to improve its performance?

Comment: This animation is as good as it gets, IMO. Are you sure it's this that's causing the issue?

Comment: Not sure about the exact problem. Just make sure you have hardware acceleration enabled in your browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356769/test-if-hardware-acceleration-has-been-enabled-for-a-css-animation

Comment: @kalpeshpatel yeah, the hardware acceleration is enabled, according to the post you provided.#

Comment: @jbutler483 Yeah, I am very sure. If I open that jsfiddle in my question, Chrome becomes slow, really noticeable slow.

Comment: it works fine on mine...Stupid suggestion: have you tried to close chrome (also the background running progress) and reopen it again? if it doesn't solve this issue, try to hard remove cache maybe? It's hard cause as i said it works more than fine on mine..

Comment: @Nick Yeah I've tried, didn't help. Is it because my graphic card -`Nvidia Quadro NVS 295` is bad? My CPU is `i7-2600S 2.8GHz`

Comment: @kalpeshpatel how can I force to use GPU lie said here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: @JacksonTale may this help you: https://www.urbaninsight.com/2013/01/04/improving-html5-app-performance-gpu-accelerated-css-transitions and http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: @kalpeshpatel yeah tried, not that helpful. a bit flicker still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your animation duration to 1s:

```
.pulse {width: 20px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;background-color: #53A653; border-radius: 100%; -webkit-animation: scaleout 1.0s infinite ease-in-out; animation: scaleout 1.0s infinite ease-in-out;}
```

EDIT: I forgot to read the line says how your scrolling became chunky. Try using Firefox (stupid suggestion). If not, it's most likely just your computer.

Comment: Your animation worked very smoothly on my side. Nice animating, by the way.