# CSS transition is not smooth when click button

Tags: css, css-transitions, buttonclick

I am trying to make a smooth effect onClick using CSS.
When I click the button, this `.mobileNav` class will be added by jQuery `addClass` method. This works fine.

But CSS transition is not working well

This is What tried so far

```css
<button class="mobileNav">button</button>
    
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top:60px;
  right:-250px;
  transition:right 1s linear;
}
.menu.mobileNav {
  right:0;
}
```

CSS transition is not smooth. What is wrong my code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not add the class `.menu` to your `button`, that's why the `transition` wasn't working, because the `transition` was added to `.menu` not to `.menu.mobileNav`, well, it's working here now, lemme know if it works for you too

```js
$(".menu").on('click', function () {
    $(".menu").addClass('mobileNav');
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .menu {
    position: absolute;
    top:60px;
    right:-250px;
    transition: right 1s linear;
  }
  
  .menu.mobileNav {
    right: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <button class="menu">button</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well properties like `left`, `top`, `bottom` and `right` are not hardware accelerated. That means your CPU needs to perform this transition on its own without the help of the GPU (if you have one witch you usually have)

For this case i would use simply `transform` witch uses hardware acceleration:

```
.menu { position: absolute; top:60px; transform: translateX(-250px); transition:transform 1s linear; }
.menu.mobileNav { transform: translateX(0) }
```

Take a look at this guys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356769/test-if-hardware-acceleration-has-been-enabled-for-a-css-animation#answer-26371807)